# How do I perform a live video streaming on iOS and Windows using PhoneGap?

Tags: xcode, cordova, video-streaming, phonegap-build, http-live-streaming

I'm having the rtmp and hls url. Also I'm aware that rtmp works with android and hls works with ios and windows.

I need to know how to integrate these in web app (phonegap apps) which will be later packaged to different platforms.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Yawar No. I couldn't.